# How can I assign 1 columns text color in ag-grid while leaving the other columns text as default?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to change all the names in a name column to blue and leave all the other columns black. I'm doing this in angular with ag-grid.

Comment: Have you tried the cellClass definition?

Comment: thats what i was using originally and it wont change the color, im not sure what is topping it.

Answer (score 0):

In you column definition add cellClass:

[image]

```
colDefs = [{
    field: 'name',
    headerName: 'Name',
    ...
    cellClass: 'color--blue'
}]
```

Comment: thats what i tried first and it still wont change the color.

Comment: @RileyBunce this is the right solution, i think you should check if there is any typo in your class name. Or can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz?